# Getting transactions in Yodlee sandbox environment

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to fetch all user transaction using executeUserSearchRequest in sandbox, but getting `{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"Exception Occurred","referenceCode":"_5e6f0985-ea74-49bc-8436-e0b015657246"}`

Could it be done in sandbox environment?

My request is:

```
transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput=true
transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter=
userSessionToken=08062013_0:a924114f74e7ddedefc5a004422a020ca3fc7080930307578559302de9bf3c8c627aaf02e99491eed69ea75570c4ea67e82b2c5523dc7f91544a4cc49a0be67b
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber=500
transactionSearchRequest.containerType=bank
cobSessionToken=08062013_0:737f4e96deca907d7554ca5f77ff482bf1bde89963bd7f74c06df67d33dea6dcce458bf399f40742c8a3f7dc8815b2775bf3291c1556489b1a195ae6dfa2467b
transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams like `transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.currencyCode` should be specified and `transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType` should be full (`ALL_TRANSACTION`).